# How does fwite/putc write to Disk?

Tags: c, fwrite, disk, stdio, fseek

Suppose we have an already existing file, say `<File>`. This file has been opened by a C program for update (`r+b`). We use `fseek` to navigate to a point inside `<File>`, other than the end of it. Now we start writing data using `fwrite/fputc`. Note that we don't delete any data previously existing in `<File>`...

How does the system handle those writes? Does it **rewrite the whole file to another position in the Disk**, now containing the new data? Does it **fragment the file and write only the new data in another position** (and just remember that in the middle there is some free space)? Does it actually **overwrite in place only the part that has changed**?

There is a good reason for asking: In the first case, if you continuously update a file, the system can get slow. In the second case, it could be faster but will mess up the File System if done to many files. In the third case, especially if you have a solid state Disk, updating the same spot of a File over and over again may render that part of the Disk useless.

Actually, that's where my question originates from. I've read that, to save Disk Sectors from overuse, Solid State Disks move Data to less used sectors, using different techniques. But how exactly does the `stdio` functions handle such situations?

Thanks in advance for your time! :D

Comment: standardlibraries like stdio don't care about disc sectors. That's what a driver is for. Also there is more involved than just writing to the disc, because the standard libraries just route the request to the operating system, which checks access rights (if appropriate) and then forward the requests to the driver. stdio is as far from the disc away as possible. stdio doesn't even know if the data is written to a disc at all. It just writes it to a standardized stream, which can be a disc, a network or some RAM, or whatever. It can also be a trashbin (aka /dev/null) :)

Comment: Also, fragementation usually occurs when you delete and write a lot. In that case a file can get "splattered" all over the disc, which makes the access slower, because the driver has to wait for more sectores to be read. When a file is written in a continous block, the driver can handle it such, that the spin (if it spins) of the disc is optimized for accessing a particular file.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful!!! :D

By the way, is there any way that you know of (apart from writing an operating system in assembly) that we can have direct access to a drive?

Comment: How to write a driver depends on the OS. However, most drivers are not written in assembly anymore. You only need small assembler parts for instructions that are not otherwise available, but the majority of the code is C or even C++. For Windows you can take a look at the DDK, which is freely downloadable. For Linux the source is available anyway. :) I would google for some open source drivers (if you go the Windows route) and take a look at them. You might take a look at ReactOS, which is a Windows OSS replacement, and is binary compatible, so you can find something in their code for sure.

Comment: Now that I think of it, you should be able to directly access a drive via the UNC paths (in Windows) and of course in Unix by accessing /dev. If you have the appropriate permissions, you can write a user space application which does direct device access, so you could write your local filesystem without writing a full driver.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'll better go that way... Need a lot of studying, though! :)

Comment: Well, if the answer helps you, you can accept it. ;)

Comment: You're right. I forgot it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fileystem handler creates a kind of dicationary writing to sectors on the disc, so when you update the content of the file, the filesystem looks up the dictionary on the disc, which tells it, in which sector on the disc the file data is located. Then it spins (or waits until the disc arrives there) and updates the appropriate sectors on the disc.

That's the short version.

So in case, of updating the file, the file is normally not moved to a new place. When you write new data to the file, appending to it, and the data doesn't fit into the existing sector, then additional sectors are allocated and the data is written there.

If you delete a file, then usually the sectors are marked as free and are reused. So only if you open a new file and rewrite it, it can happen that the file is put in different sectors than before.

But the details can vary, depending on the hardware. AFAIK if you overwrite data on a CD, then the data is newly written (as long as the session is not finalized), because you can not update data on a CD, once it is written.

Comment: This means that it writes over the old data? But is that true for SSD drives too?

Comment: How the data is written, depends mostly on the filesystem driver. AFAIK using FAT on an SSD is not such a good thing, because it tends to overwrite the same sectors often. So a filesystem which distributes it better, is a better choice, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is incorrect: **"Note that we don't delete any data previously existing in File"**

If you seek into the middle of a file and start writing it will write over whatever was at that position before.

How this is done under the covers probably depends on how computer in the hard disk implements it. It's supposed to be invisible outside the hard disk and shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes, that's what we want to do. By my comment, I was just trying to mention that we don't truncate the file to zero length deleting all data (say using `wb`).

Comment: There is a case when it matters: when you want to overwrite data in purpose!!! :D

Comment: You can't shorten a file with the write() method. You can only change existing data or add to the end of the file.